# Intelligent Mercurial Bundles in USB Key from Work to Home and viceversa

Tags: bash, mercurial, sed, awk

This is a common question I know, but I want to take it to the next level, I know how to use bundles, but is kind of boring having to dig trough the "hg log" to see my last changes, so I want to make it automatic, checking my log trough bash/awk and identifying work/home changes trough date and mail, (I have diferent mails in .hgrc, me@work and me@home).

I already have this bash function but I have to pass the base revision manually:

```
hgb () {
    hg bundle --base $1 ~/changes-`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M`.hg
}
```

So I would like something like:

```
mkwbundle #make work bundle for home
```

and:

```
mkhbundle #make home bundle for work
```

I'm just beginning at awk/sed but I've seen miracles, I ask before doing it with Python which is my goto tool for almost anything.

Update:

For mercurial agnostic people, this is how hg log looks like:

```
changeset:   28:f5200232460e
tag:         tip
user:        Manuel@home
date:        Tue Jan 15 23:39:57 2013 -0500
summary:     Adding DevTodo

changeset:   27:828dbba6830a
user:        Manuel@home
date:        Tue Jan 15 23:24:57 2013 -0500
summary:     login twig

changeset:   26:781477f86f6f
user:        Manuel@home
date:        Tue Jan 15 00:18:54 2013 -0500
summary:     UI mockup

changeset:   25:0c9365b200a8
user:        Manuel@home
date:        Mon Jan 14 23:50:22 2013 -0500
summary:     using twig blocks, remember reuse parent

changeset:   24:a1abfcfcefed
user:        Manuel@work
date:        Mon Jan 14 23:49:44 2013 -0500
summary:     smaller footer

changeset:   23:3cd12b7fb684
user:        Manuel@work
date:        Mon Jan 14 23:20:18 2013 -0500
summary:     test content width
```

I want to get the base revision when in work to make a bundle, let's say I started working in rev 24 at home and made 4 changes, then I'm in 28, I want to get 24 as base rev and make a bundle, then the same at work.

EDIT: per @dhunter comment below, the expected output of the script would be:

```
24
```

Comment: I didn't get what you want to automatically do. it seems that you sync your two hg repo not by pull/push but bundles/unbundles. you want to automatically get the rev no for the --base right? say Work you have 1-10 rev. now from bundle of Home, you imported 11-13 rev. you go on working on Work repo, and add 14-16. so you want to auto get 14. ?

Comment: Since you're looking for awk/sed help and many of the people who could provide that help may not be familiar with Mercurial, please edit your post to add sufficient details on the file names or contents from which you want to extract the base revision. (e.g. "I want to extract '525' from this line: 'Mercurial base revision #525 2013-01-16'").

Comment: another question, are there other users pushing to your repository?

Comment: Speaking as someone with 30 years of sed/awk experience - I haven't the faintest idea what you're talking about. If you want to know how to transform some text, post a sample of that text and the expected output you want after running a tool on that text. If you're doing something other than transforming text then neither sed nor awk are the right tools for the job.

Comment: David done, Kent no, just me. Ed from what I looked at these days awk seems the right tool.

Comment: @dhunter , you want to have 25, not 24 right?

Comment: Actually 24, is the common revision in both clones, home and work.

Comment: @EdMorton he didn't explain how hg bundle worked. If I were him, I won't mention hg bundle, just give some hg log output as my input example, and asking for the target revision number as output. of course explain the rule of extraction. But I think he has learned something about how to ask an awk/sed question. :)

Comment: @Kent I surely did. Don't distract the wise men with stories just plain text. ;)

Comment: Looks like you've posted sample input, if you can just post the expected output now then we can get going on a solution.

Comment: @EdMorton the expected output is the first revision that differs from the last one mail. See, the last one is made at home (Manuel@home), so the other 3, BUT the 24th is made at work (Manuel@work), so when in home and I've made changes I want to get the last change I left at work, so I create the bundle (basically a compressed bunch of diffs) and apply those changes when arrive the next day at work. Kent's solution is working perfectly so far, I tried exploiting it and nothing, rock solid awk. ^_^

Comment: @dhunter glad you got a solution, wish you could have just posted some sample output though rather than trying to describe it as I'd have liked to take a crack at it but if it's not worthwile to you to spend the time creating and posting expected the output, it's not worthwhile for me to try to figure it out. I'm not trying to be rude when I say that, it's just the way it is....

Comment: I did put the output, is in the paragraph below the sample input.

Comment: Excuse me, but: **why you don't want to use revset** in bundle (if transferring repo on stick isn't solution)??? I wrote it now, rather fast, and it's transparent

Comment: Explain yourself, what I want to achieve is transferring all my changes from one repo to another, not only one but many, don't have connection between repos just different emails in hgrc to differentiate. Is there a native mercurial solution for this specific workflow?

Comment: @dhunter - no, you didn't put the output, you put a paragraph describing what characteristics you'd like the output to have using some domain-specific terminology. I don't know what all that stuff about base revisions and bundles and doing stuff from work vs home means - simply post the expected output, that's all.

Comment: @EdMorton "I want to get 24" that was my expected output.

Comment: @dhunter I'd never have guessed you just wanted the number 24 printed given the paragraph you posted beneath your sample input. Thanks for clarifying, I've modified your question to show that expected output. Please just do that if you have future questions. I've no idea why the number 24 would be the expected output but it sounds like you already have the solution you wanted so that's great.

Comment: Thanks for the help @EdMorton I'll do it like that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Revset version for `hg bundle --base REV` type of command

**Used**: revsets, revsets aliases

**Task in a verbal form**: find latest changeset, after which to tip changesets continuously created by another author, than sought-for changeset

**Solution**:

*Iteration 1*

`max(user('work'))` for bundle with changesets, intended to be transferred **to work** (all after latest "work" is homework)

`max(user('home'))` for bundle with changesets, intended to be transferred **to home** (all after latest "home" is workplacework)

*Iteration 2*

Compacting and beautification: I'm too lazy for too much typing. Bundleable() function-name shortened to ba() and added to in the "revsetalias" section of a Mercurial configuration file for home and work repos

```
 [revsetalias]
 ba('$1') = max(user('$1'))
```

('$1' instead of $1 used in order to don't write '' around parameter - signal string - by hand)

**Results**

`hg bundle --base "ba(home)"` or `hg bundle --base "ba(work)"`

home|work define *destination, for which bundle have to be prepared*

Comment: Ah, one of those little moments when you love using mercurial. Thank you @LazyBadger, didn't knew about this secret language, I'll dig into that. Can I accept more than one answer? I involved awk in the question and Kent's answer may not be optimal in a mercurial POV but didactically is really helpful.

Comment: No, accepted can be only "accepted by you" answer. BTW, I wrote some time after posting this version V2 of revset without using parameter at all

Comment: The iteration 2 of the post you say?

Comment: @dhunter - no, iteration 2 is V1, parametrized command. I wrote command, which can write on both sides without any difference in syntax

Comment: I read some more about revision sets and added this to the command: max(user('home')) and not head(), to find the last change made at home only if is not the last one (i.e. I made some more at work). Could you post the new command you said?

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is you want to get the rev No# for your hgb() $1.

So let's make an example. If you run `hg log` on your work:

```
**(some information were omitted)**

changeset: xxx
user:me@work

changeset: xxx
user:someoneelse@work.com

changeset: xxx
user:me@work

changeset: 777:234asdf2342
user:me@work

changeset: xxx-border-xxx
user:me@home

changeset: xxxx
user:me@home
```

then you may want to have `777`. which means from the **tip**, you check users, and found the changeset with the user change either from `me@home->@work` or `me@work -> me@home` in the example above, it is the `changeset xxx-border-xxx`. then you take the previous changeset rev. from that rev, you want to make a bundle, and import to your home/work repo. I hope I understood you right. However you really should make your question clear.

Anyway.... of course it could be done by awk, take the example above (branch,date,summary were omitted)

```
hg log| awk -vRS="" 'NR==1{p=$0~/me@work/?"me@work":"me@home";l=$2}NR>1 {if($0!~p){print l;exit}else l=$2}'
```

if use the example above:

output is:

```
777:234asdf2342
```

if try with the example in your question, we have to change the email addr then the awk-oneliner is:

```
hg log| awk -vRS="" 'NR==1{p=$0~/Manuel@work/?"Manuel@work":"Manuel@home";l=$2}NR>1 {if($0!~p){print l;exit}else l=$2}'
```

output is:

```
25:0c9365b200a8
```

I use hg alot, but bundle not. If you really mean to get 24 rev. for your --base, then look at this:

```
 awk -vRS="" 'NR==1{p=$0~/Manuel@work/?"Manuel@work":"Manuel@home";}NR>1{if($0!~p){print $2;exit}}'
```

this gives you:

```
24:a1abfcfcefed
```

**NOTE**

**don't generate bundle with the awk line if there is no changeset ci at all since last unbundle. It will repeat generating last bundle. You should know if it was changed right?**

Comment: Thumbs up!! Thanks, I just added "| awk -F: '{print $1}" and got my base revision, now I have to study your awk is really dense, I'm loving it.

Comment: @dhunter actually you could do everything in one awk process. but ok, important is you solved your problem. i am glad if my post could give you some help.

Comment: I'm planning to read the sed & awk book 2ed of march 1997, is it worth it or is outdated? I use mostly mawk in *nix systems.

Comment: @dhunter I have some basic awk/sed skills, if you ask me that question. I would suggest that, read some very basic awk/sed articles, get the idea. then come back here, read those high voted good awk/sed  questions/answers, (don't try to answer question first,just understand answers. since 99% questions here are from real world). after a couple of weeks, you could start answering questions, in the meantime, you get a lot of magic usages as well. good luck.

Comment: Found the canonical way to filter the revision: |cut -d: -f1

Comment: @dhunter - don't get that sed&awk book. You don't need a book to learn the stuff sed should be used for, and there's a better awk book - Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition By Arnold Robbins (http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/awkprog3/). Also, get a more full-featured awk like GNU awk (gawk) as mawk is minimal-featured for improved performance which is rarely needed. Finally - you do NOT need to pipe awk output to cut!

Comment: @EdMorton +1    for your opinion and the pipe comment. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @EdMorton, sorry for all the piping, I guess when you have a hammer...

Comment: Yes. I always advertise the book rather than the online version (which is always available as a reference) though because the author deserves to make a few bucks off it for all his work on GNU awk and the book plus AFAIK the changes between the book and the online document are gawk-specific so the books still at least as useful a starting point for learning awk.

Comment: Well, with more pipes and templated log I can suggest a lot shorter one-liner. Is it needed?